# storing the string from kafkaStream into a variable for processing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I need to get my messages from a Kafka producer and from the messages I need to find the words that contain `%` and generate a message for different `%` values. Finally I need to send it to ElasticSearch.

I am able to see the values in console using `kafkaStream.print()` but I need to process the string to match with required keywords and generate the message.

My code:

```
package rnd

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Minutes, Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object WordFind {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
    val checkpointDir = "/usr/local/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.2/checkpoint/"

    import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds

    val batchIntervalSeconds = 2
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))

    import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

    val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("wordcounttopic" -> 5))

    val s = kafkaStream.print()
    println(" the words are: " + s)
    ssc.remember(Minutes(1))
    ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDir)
    ssc
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(batchIntervalSeconds * 5 * 1000)
  }
}
```

If I pass "The usage is 75%" through the Lafka producer I should generate a message saying "Increase ram by 25%" in ElasticSearch.

The output that I am getting is:

```
18/02/09 16:38:27 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:37879 with 2.4 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 37879)
18/02/09 16:38:27 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
18/02/09 16:38:27 WARN StreamingContext: spark.master should be set as local[n], n > 1 in local mode if you have receivers to get data, otherwise Spark jobs will not get resources to process the received data.
 ***the words are: ()***
```

I want the String that i am passing in place of () in 's'.

Comment: `kafkaStream.print` doesn't return a `String` to print, but performs the actual printing. What you are printing is `()`, the singleton value for type `Unit` (which you can thing of as `void` in Java, if you are familiar with it.

Comment: Then how do i get the value as a string? I need to do some pattern matching on the message that is coming from kafka. How do i convert the value as a string to do the pattern match ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The val `kafkaStream` is a `RecieverInputDStream[(String, String)]`, where the data is `(kafkaMetaData, kafkaMessage)` 
for more information see [https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f830bb9170f6b853565d9dd30ca7418b93a54fe3/external/kafka-0-8/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaInputDStream.scala#L135 ].

We need to extract the second of the tuple and do the pattern matching (i.e filter RecieverInputDStream find the words that contain %) and then use map to generate output (i.e a message for different % values). And as mentioned by @stefanobaghino, the print() function just prints the output to the console and doesn't return any string of the record.

for example:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream
val kafkaStream: ReceiverInputDStream[(String, String)] = KafkaUtils.createStream(sparkStreamingContext, "localhost:2181",
  "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("wordcounttopic" -> 5))

import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
val filteredStream: DStream[(String, String)] = kafkaStream
  .filter(record => record._2.contains("%")) // TODO : pattern matching here

val outputDStream: DStream[String] = filteredStream
  .map(record => record._2.toUpperCase()) // just assuming some operation
outputDStream.print()
```

Use the outputDStream to be written into ElasticSearch. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will try this and let you know.

Comment: Hello Pavithran, Thank you so much for the help. As i am very new to kafka, can you help me with how do i generate different messages for different values of % ?
e.g. if the value coming is <50% - message: the cpu usage is fine
if 50-70% - message 10% increase reqd

Comment: Sure @s.c., can you please create a new question and have a detailed description of the same... since, in stackoverflow each post must have only one question to answer for and the new post will be open to all to answer the doubt you have. Please provide a sample of the data as the % calculation doesn't give clear picture. Also read : [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]

Comment: Hi Pavithran I have posted a different question with my scenario in the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747604/spark-streaming-on-kafka-print-different-cases-for-different-values-from-kafka
Can you please help me with the code. Please let me know if any doubts in the scenario. 
Thank you

Comment: Okay sure. I am new to stackoverflow too. Trying how to mark it as answered. Please help me with the other question

Comment: It says page not found. But i will try other way and mark it answered. Thank you so much. Pls help me with my other question mentioned earlier. Thanks again

Comment: Please add sample input output for the other question.

Comment: I added the sample input format and the output message in the question and marked this as answered.

Comment: Please help me with the other question. Thank you